# ORA-04024: self-deadlock detected while trying to mutex pin cursor with no problematic SQL Plan Baseline

Tags: oracle12c, audit-trail

I've inherited a task to apply an all-encompassing unified audit policy on an Oracle 12.1.0.2 database.
All actions on auditable objects, past, and future need to be audited.

Following Oracle documentation I came up with the following script, which works well (after a lot of trials and errors) and without errors:

```
--create initial audit policy and set it to audit the first object in your list of auditable objects

create audit policy Audit_All actions all on sys.icol$;

--get a list of what you need to audit
define object_type_pattern = '(Directory|java Source|java Class|java Resource|Library|MATERIALIZED VIEW|MINING MODEL|PACKAGE|FUNCTION|PROCEDURE|SEQUENCE|TABLE|VIEW|type)';

-- alter the audit policy to audit all the rest of your auditable objects

declare
  v_cmnd varchar2(1000);
  no_such_object EXCEPTION;
  iot_overflow_table EXCEPTION;
  it_are_external_table EXCEPTION;
  invalid_audit_option EXCEPTION;
  pragma exception_init(no_such_object, -942);
  pragma exception_init(iot_overflow_table, -25191);
  pragma exception_init(it_are_external_table, -30657);
  pragma exception_init(invalid_audit_option, -46359);
begin
  for c in (select owner, object_name from dba_objects where regexp_instr(object_type, '&object_type_pattern') != 0)
    LOOP
        begin
            v_cmnd := 'alter audit policy Audit_All add actions all on ' || c.owner || '.' || '"'|| c.object_name ||'"';
            dbms_output.put_line(v_cmnd);
            execute immediate v_cmnd;
            EXCEPTION 
            WHEN no_such_object then dbms_output.put_line( 'Object does not exist, will not run ' || v_cmnd);
            WHEN iot_overflow_table then dbms_output.put_line( 'iot table issue faced, will not run ' || v_cmnd);
            WHEN it_are_external_table then dbms_output.put_line( 'This is an externally organized table, will not run ' || v_cmnd);
            WHEN invalid_audit_option then dbms_output.put_line( 'Invalid audit option for this object, will not run ' || v_cmnd);
        END;
    end loop;
end;
/

--alter the policy to add auditing on all system actions:

alter audit policy Audit_All add actions all;

--enable your policy:

audit policy Audit_All;
```

When I run the last query to enable the audit policy I get this:

```
SYS@orcl>audit policy Audit_All ;
audit policy Audit_All 
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3
ORA-04024: self-deadlock detected while trying to mutex pin cursor 0x07E9E1BB0
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3
ORA-04024: self-deadlock detected while trying to mutex pin cursor 0x07E9E1BB0
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3
ORA-04024: self-deadlock detected while trying to mutex pin cursor 0x07E917A40
Process ID: 2667
Session ID: 48 Serial number: 37985
```

I googled this error code and found an Oracle documentation that says this is caused by an unpublished Bug 21196809 - ORA-04024: SELF-DEADLOCK DETECTED WHILE TRYING TO MUTEX PIN CURSOR.
Their solution is to upgrade to Oracle 12.2, which is not something I can do.

Another solution given is a workaround of removing the SQL Plan Baseline for the recursive SQL statement above.
I ran

```
SELECT SQL_HANDLE, SQL_TEXT, PLAN_NAME, ORIGIN, ENABLED, ACCEPTED FROM DBA_SQL_PLAN_BASELINES WHERE  SQL_TEXT LIKE 'audit policy Imperva_All';
```

And it came back empty. I don't know what to remove. The database is inoperable until I reboot the whole machine.

The problem is re-creatable. The alert log was a little too long to put here, so it's [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-Rb2WQzHv1sY73LspgrNmOETDkI8ucaJ/view?usp=sharing)